# SQL Server - applying a role to a user. "select failed because the following set options quoted_identifier"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've restored a large database from another machine to my local machine. And have recreated the same user account. But when I try and apply db_datareader or db_datawriter I get
"SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verifiy that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query norifications"

I can the role to this user for other databases.
I don't have any indexed views. Maybe it's an index on a computed column.

How can I track this down?

Comment: Are you saying to get the error from SSMS when adding a user to the built-in database roles or is this when the user executes queries? Did you use backup/restore? I'd expect that to preserve all the original database settings. Filtered indexes also require the ANSI settings but I'm not sure how that comes into play here.

Comment: It's from SMSS when trying to apply the role. I did backup/restore

Comment: Do you get the same error with T-SQL `ALTER ROLE...ADD MEMBER`?

Comment: It's 2008
Using
sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'myusername'

Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure rds_deny_backups_trigger, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 10]
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: Does your SSMS query window session have QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON? I added the SQL 2008 tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to tell. But I've tried set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON and OFF before the sp_addrolemember and I get the same

Comment: BTW, the `rds_deny_backups_trigger` looks to be a server-level trigger. Make sure it was created with QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and ANSI_NULLS ON. This may be a problem on the target server, not the backup/restore.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Dan. I have managed to solve the problem (or work round it at least). This is a dev machine... I've been able to change the user to "sysadmin" server role. I still can't add to db_datareader, but I have enough permissions now anyway, and since it's only dev I'm not concerned the users permissions are elevated.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll add an answer detailing how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a server trigger being fired by `sp_addrolemember` that has `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`. Both `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` and `ANSI_NULLS` are "sticky" settings so the settings in effect when the trigger was created are used at execution time. The `OFF` setting is for legacy compatibility and should not be used going forward.

The best practice is to create procs, triggers, etc. with these setting ON to ensure compatibility with newer SQL Server features. Have your DBA drop and recreate the server trigger with the settings `ON`.